# Regarding file download in PHP

Tags: php, download

I am working on a project where I need a download feature for videos, as of now my download code is below

```
 header("Cache-Control: public");
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
 header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
 header("Content-Type: video/webm");
 header("Content-Type: video/flv");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 readfile($downloadUrl);
```

The above code works fine. But the thing is my file format can be any type for eg. .flv, .mp4,.3gp.

So, My question is the above code requires to pass  Content-Type for each type. Is there a generic Content-Type that I can pass which supports all file formats.

Comment: I don't think that you have to specify content-type at all. It is just a hint for the browser how to handle it. You are downloading the file anyway. If you must use content-type, let it be `application`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: `application/octet-stream`. If you're not interested in opening the file this mime type tells the browser the file is of some unspecified type and can only be saved to disk.

Answer (score 4):

In common case you can use just

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream')
```

Sending specific content-type just helps client to understand what application should be used to open incoming file. Since you're sending content-disposition attachment, there is no need to open a file.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
header("Content-Type: ".mime_content_type($downloadUrl));
```